What is an inertial frame in terms of acceleration?
After learning about the difference between coordinate and proper acceleration, I am now confused on the precise definition of an inertial reference frame in terms of proper and coordinate acceleration, in the context of special and general relativity.
In special relativity, an inertial frame is a frame with zero acceleration (zero proper acceleration?) and where Newton's laws hold and there are no fictitious forces.
In general relativity, it seems like gravity is now viewed as another kind of fictitious force and an inertial frame is now defined as a frame with zero proper acceleration and fictitious forces including gravity is absent (?) Under this definition, any frame where you are in weightless state (e.g. stranded in outer space or undergoing free fall in some gravitational field) is considered as inertial frames, right? So a frame where you feel gravity (without other fictitious forces) is considered as inertial frame in special relativity but not in general relativity?

In Newtonian or SR, inertial frame= zero coord acceleration. In GR, a free falling frame (geodesic) isn't inertial. You can define local inertial frame where coord acceleration is zero (Riemann normal coordinates)...but it's only an approximation

In terms of acceleration an inertial frame is a reference frame where all objects with zero coordinate acceleration also have zero proper acceleration.
This condition implements Newton’s first law. Force-free objects are identified by zero proper acceleration and traveling at a constant speed in a straight line is identified by zero coordinate acceleration. Hence such frames implement Newton’s concept of inertia and are therefore called inertial frames.
The difference between SR and GR is only that in SR inertial frames are global while in GR inertial frames are local. Gravity is locally indistinguishable from a fictitious force in GR, and in SR it is globally indistinguishable from a fictitious force (and limited to fields with no tidal effects).

Under this definition, any frame where you are in weightless state (e.g. stranded in outer space or undergoing free fall in some gravitational field) is considered as inertial frames, right?

Yes. Again, locally in GR and globally in SR, and with the clarification that we are talking about the weightless object's rest frame.

So a frame where you feel gravity (without other fictitious forces) is considered as inertial frame in special relativity but not in general relativity?

Such a frame is not inertial in either GR or SR. Also, there isn't a way to identify frames where you feel gravity but not other fictitious forces. So that requires a bit of handwaving, but I think we can get away with it if we don't look too hard at edge cases.

Thanks, can you elaborate on why zero coordinate acceleration implies zero proper acceleration? Is the converse true as well?

Assuming that we stand on some inertial frame, how do we know whether a frame has zero coordinate acceleration or not? If the frame has nonzero coordinate acceleration, then what if the inertial frame we are standing on is also accelerating at the same rate and it gives an illusion that the frame has zero coordinate acceleration?

@user366875 for your first question I added an extra paragraph to the answer. For your second question it isn’t frames that have coordinate acceleration. It is objects that have coordinate acceleration with respect to a given frame. An object has no coordinate acceleration in a frame if the second derivative of its position in that frame is zero.

So you are saying it is true that a frame has zero coordinate acceleration only if it has zero proper acceleration? It seems like the converse is false because a frame of an observer in free fall on Earth has zero proper acceleration but has nonzero coordinate acceleration (before reaching terminal velocity?).

Also, I read the another answer of yours. I now think it is more useful to think in terms of pseudoforces (or fictitious forces) than acceleration. I think I can simply say that a frame is inertial if and only if the equation of motion of a particle in that frame is $f^\mu=m \frac{d^2 x^\mu}{d\tau^2}$ (the contribution from fictitious forces is zero: $m \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} \frac{dx^\alpha}{d\tau} \frac{dx^\beta}{d\tau}=0$).

@user366875 said "It seems like the converse is false because a frame of an observer in free fall on Earth has zero proper acceleration but has nonzero coordinate acceleration (before reaching terminal velocity?)." I think that is essentially correct with the caveat that the frame only has nonzero coordinate acceleration from the point of view of an external accelerating observer. Usually an observer considers themselves to be at rest with their own reference frame by definition and they never consider themselves to have coordinate acceleration (relative to their own coordinates system).

@user366875 yes, I like the Christoffel-symbol definition too. Regarding "you are saying it is true that a frame has zero coordinate acceleration only if it has zero proper acceleration?" Again (the third time) at no point here do I mention the acceleration of a frame. I am always speaking of the acceleration of objects. Talking about the acceleration of a frame does not make sense. In the (local) frame of an observer in free fall objects with zero proper acceleration also have zero coordinate acceleration, so that is an inertial frame. The converse is also true, but is not what you stated

Why do you think that a frame of a free falling observer is globally inertial in SR?


In special relativity, an inertial frame is a frame with zero
acceleration (zero proper acceleration?) and where Newton's laws hold
and there are no fictitious forces.

EDIT: In light of the comment by @ProfRob I have rewritten this first section:
If by the Newtonian laws of physics, we restrict ourselves to just Newton's 3 laws of motion, then the statement is essentially correct with a small caveat for the 2nd law. Newton's 2nd law can be stated as $F = ma$ or $F = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}$. When stated as $F = ma$, this law does not hold, but when stated in the form of change in momentum per unit time ($F = \mathrm{d}p/\mathrm{d}t$), the 2nd law does hold in an inertial frame.
It is not clear (to me) if the 2nd and 3rd laws fail in an accelerating reference frame. I think it is reasonable to conclude that if the observer feels no proper acceleration and the 1st law holds, then that is sufficient to define a inertial reference frame.

So a frame where you feel gravity (without other fictitious forces) is
considered as inertial frame in special relativity but not in general
relativity?

No. A frame where you feel gravity is not considered an inertial frame in either SR or GR. On the surface of the Earth, you can measure your own proper acceleration by standing on some bathroom scales, so you are not in an inertial reference frame when standing on the surface of the Earth in either SR or GR.

What is an inertial frame in terms of acceleration?

If an observer measures their own proper acceleration to be zero then they are locally in an inertial reference frame. If they set out an extended grid of clocks that are all at rest with respect to themselves and all the clocks appear to be running at the same rate and the speed of light is measured to be constant in all directions over that extended region, then they can consider themselves to be in an extended inertial reference frame.
There is a notion of a momentary inertial reference frame for an observer that is accelerating relative to an inertial observer. If the instantaneous velocity of the accelerating observer is $u$, then the time dilation of accelerating observer is equal to that of a momentarily co-moving inertial observer ($t = t'\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}$) and over a very short time and space interval we can treat the accelerating observer as if they were moving inertially.

So textbooks that say Newton's laws hold in inertial frames are wrong? Maybe I misread.

@user366875 Perhaps you need to read the small print ;-) That statement is only (approximately) true for low relative velocities. The laws of special relativity hold in inertial reference frames.

What do you think of the experiment outlined here? The "inertial" lab frame where one experiences Earth's gravity is not inertial frame in your definition?

The "inertial reference frame" in that experiment is only approximately inertial. It assumes the difference in clock rates due to gravitational time dilation over a height of about one metre is zero, but strictly speaking it is not. It could be described as a localised and approximate inertial reference frame. It is a reasonable approximation. It would be difficult (but not impossible) to measure the difference but with modern atomic clocks it can be done.

Newton's laws (first, second and third, and all other laws of physics) apply in all inertial frames in SR.

(+1) In analogy to a flowing river, an "inertial frame" is then an object that is moving with the current (neither rowing against nor rowing into the local current)?

„In classical physics and special relativity, an inertial frame of reference (also called inertial space, or Galilean reference frame) is a stationary or uniformly moving frame of reference.“ Wiki.
The problem with this definition is the use of the words uniform and moving. The former implicitly assumes that time passes at the same rate in all frames, and the latter describes a relation "to move with respect to", which is not an equivalence relation. The remedy for this problem is to replace the word move with the word rest. The relation "to rest with respect to" is an equivalence relation that divides the open set of all reference frames into equivalence classes called frames of rest.  Remarkably, the constancy of time plays no role here, and the relation "to move with respect to" is just the negation of the rest relation. Obviously, the open set of all frames of rest can only be associated with tardyons.  Its closure, however, includes the luxons and tachyons, i.e. particles that do not rest in any frame of reference.
So what is an inertial frame in terms of acceleration?
The inertial frame is the frame of rest with zero acceleration, i.e. a frame that remains in its equivalence class.

Ok, let me summarize what I learned so far:

Theorem. The following statements are equivalent:

You are standing on (locally) inertial frame.

Your accelerometer reading is zero.

You feel zero proper acceleration.

There are no fictitious or pseudo forces (including gravitation) in your frame.

Christoffel symbols vanish (locally).

All laws of physics are satisfied.



Regarding (5), in general relativity, 4-acceleration $A=(A^0, A^1, A^2, A^3)$, in general (pun intended), can be written as
$$A^\alpha=\frac{dU^\alpha}{d\tau}+\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\alpha U^\mu U^\nu$$
where $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\alpha U^\mu U^\nu$ represents acceleration contribution from spacetime geometry (this is source of all the fictitious forces like coriolis force for example).
Suppose you are at rest in some inertial frame and are grasping an apple in your hand. When you release the apple, it either will remain stationary or move in a straight line (yes, the apple feels zero proper acceleration and the frame of the apple is inertial). Why? The equation of motion for the apple of mass $m$ can be written as
$$f^\alpha=mA^\alpha=m\frac{dU^\alpha}{d\tau}+m\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\alpha U^\mu U^\nu=0$$
where $U$, $A$, and $f$ are apple's 4-velocity, 4-acceleration and 4-force respectively. Since we are in an inertial frame, Christoffel symbols vanish, i.e. $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\alpha=0$ for all $\mu=0,1,2,3$ and $\nu=0,1,2,3$. So the fictitious force contribution is zero: $m\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\alpha U^\mu U^\nu=0$. The equation of motion is now $m\frac{dU^\alpha}{d\tau}=-m\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\alpha U^\mu U^\nu=0$. So the apple will remain in rest or move in a straight line.
If we are standing on the surface of Earth (assume the Earth is an infinite plane with uniform gravitational field $g$), which is non-inertial frame, then the apple's equation of motion (in z-direction) will be $m\frac{dU^3}{d\tau}=-m\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^3 U^\mu U^\nu\approx-mg$ (for other components, $m\frac{dU^0}{d\tau}=m\frac{dU^1}{d\tau}=m\frac{dU^2}{d\tau}=0$) instead. The apple falls downwards with acceleration of $g$, in agreement with Newtonian mechanics.
Let me know if I made any misleading statements!

I would recommend changing 4 a little. You never “feel” fictitious forces regardless of your reference frame. You only ever feel real forces. So I would change 4 to “There are no fictitious forces in your frame”

@Dale Thanks for the suggestion. I hope everything else is okay.
